# Laravel Eloquent: Retrieve "second level" relationship entity

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've 3 entity:

```
Owner
-id

Car
-id
-owner_id
-brand_id

Brand
-id
```

I would like to retrieve all `brand` of the `cars` of an `owner`.

Now, if I do in the `Owner` class

```
$this->cars()->with('brand');
```

I receive a `Database/Eloquent/Collection` like this:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {
    all: [
        App\Car {
            id: 1,
            owner_id: 10,
            brand_id: 100,
            brand: App\Brand {
                id: 100
            },
        },
        App\Car {
            id: 2,
            owner_id: 10,
            brand_id: 200,
            brand: App\Brand {
                id: 200
            },
        },
        App\Car {
            id: 3,
            owner_id: 10,
            brand_id: 100,
            brand: App\Brand {
                id: 100
            },
        },
    ],
}
```

but I would like to have a structure like this:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {
    all: [
        App\Brand {
            id: 100
        },
        App\Brand {
            id: 200
        },
}
```

Is it possible in some way?

Comment: Have you tried using the Laravel QueryBuilder? [Example](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins)

Comment: you could try `belongsToMany()`

Comment: I updated my answer, can you check it again?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `hasManyThrough` relationship on the `Owner` model.

For example:

```
public function brands()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Brand::class, Car::class);
}
```

Comment: Well in this way is necessary that `Brand` has a foreign_key to `Car`, right?

Comment: no, it requires Car belongs to Brand which is what you have currently.

Comment: I receive the error that `Brand` has not `car_id` field

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to choose,

- You may use features of [Eloquent Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-collections) and filter/map your object to convert it to the form you want.
- You can define another relation on your model using [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

Simple example (you may required to set column names as a parameter.);

```
public function brands() { 
     return $this->hasManyThrough(Brand::class, Car::class);
}
```

Also you may use belongsToMany, if you don't have foreign key on your second level table (it doesn't sound well, but it works).

**Notice that, second parameter should be replaced with the name of Car table.**

```
public function brands(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Brand::class, 'cars', 'owner_id', 'brand_id');
}
```

Comment: Well in this way is necessary that `Brand` has a foreign_key to `Car`, right?